# Intel HD Graphics 530 with i915 dirver render latency

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel

I have an desktop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed and only Intel HD Graphics 530 graphics card.
It seems that i915 driver installed automatically and works however, it seems that there is lag (latency) in rendering (smth about ~100ms) which is especially noticeable when dragging mouse.

When using windows on the same computer there is no such problem.

How can investigate, where can be problem?

Comment: When you run `sudo update-initramfs -u` do you get "Possible missing firmware" warning message?

Comment: unfortunately (fortunately?) not, only `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-29-generic`